# Permission Denial: opening provider Adobe Reader

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, permission-denied

I have problem with my app when I use code:

```
 Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider

In Manifest I try add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader"/>
```

But I have all time this error when I want cursor from uri from Adobe Reader or InputStream...

Help me pls :)
Thanks for all

Ralph

Comment: are you testing on API 23?

Answer (score 0):

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.adobe.reader"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.Services.ShareService$CloseButtonListener" />
    <receiver android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.MainApplication.DocumentDetailsFragment$ServiceReceiver" />

    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.DiagnosticActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.FirstApplicationRunActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.MainApplication.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.ChooseStartupScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.ConnectToActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.ConfigSummarySuccessActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.ConfigSummaryFailureActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.ShareActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/rtf" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/msword" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/doc" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/docx" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.EnterShop"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.StartupConfigPages.ManualPairDeviceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_manual_pair_device" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.MainApplication.SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.Services.ShareService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.Services.DownloadService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.FilePicker.BackHandlingFilePickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FilePickerTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.Services.DownloadAllService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.MainApplication.FeedbackActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="pl.coig.intradokmobile.Models.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

**Part of code where I use content uri from Adobe Reader**

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);



InputStream inputStream  = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

**Uri from Adobe Reader is somethink like that**

> content://com.adobe.reader.fileprovider/root_external/storage/emulated/0/Download/Adobe%2
>   0Acrobat/document.pdf

**I get this Uri from Intent**

```
Uri fileUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider from ProcessRecord{1f7f73c1 16260:pl.coig.intradokmobile/u0a133} (pid=16260, uid=10133) that is not exported from uid 10092
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3350)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4664)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2533)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1442)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:462)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
        at pl.coig.intradokmobile.Models.FileManager.getRealPathFromURI(FileManager.java:451)
        at pl.coig.intradokmobile.Models.FileManager.getFileFromUri(FileManager.java:358)
        at pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.Services.ShareService.handleSendFile(ShareService.java:320)
        at pl.coig.intradokmobile.UserInterface.Services.ShareService.onHandleIntent(ShareService.java:103)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Add complete Manifest File

Comment: I add now full Manifest File.

Comment: you have not added any provided service that's the reason of your error

Comment: <provider     
android:name="com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider"
android:authorities="com.adobe.reader.misc..contentprovider"       
android:exported="true">
</provider>   try this

Comment: I can't add this provider. Android-studio doesn't  see com.adobe.reader.misc.ARFileProvider

Comment: And why I should add my service provider when I want use Adobe Reader provider.

Comment: If someone help me ?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showPdf(String path) { 

    Uri uri = getUri(path);
    Intent intent =intentForOtherApps(uri);
    Intent openintent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");

    try{
        startActivity(openintent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){

    }
    }
}
private Intent intentForOtherApps(Uri imageUriforPDF) {
    Intent openpdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openpdfIntent.setDataAndType(imageUriforPDF, "application/pdf");
    openpdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    openpdfIntent.addFlags(PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 23 ) {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().
                queryIntentActivities(openpdfIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(packageName, imageUriforPDF, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }

    openpdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
    openpdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    return openpdfIntent;
}
private Uri getUri(String path) {
    Uri fileUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
            "myprovider.fileprovider",
            new File(path));
    return fileUri;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.